How to set Flutter flutter_radio_player or audio_service show iOS control center live type
First question
With Flutter's package flutter_radio_player, it natively show the "LIVE" mention on control center 
So my question is : how can I customize artist, title and the image metadatas ?
Second question
If I do not choose to work with flutter_radio_player and choose instead audio_service or just_audio, I'm able to customize iOS control center metadatas.
So, my question is : how am I able to display the "LIVE" mention ?
Thanks
